# PHP => Call to non-existing class constants, way to handle?

Tags: php

just like the `__call` magic method we can use in PHP to hook a call to a non defined method, is there a way to hook a call to an undefined constant or variable?

Like `A::B`, where `B` doesn't exist.

Comment: When you go to the [`__call` manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php), you can discover a lot of other so called magic functions. You might be interested in [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Constants are evaluated at opcode compile time not runtime, so there's no way to 'catch' them.  There is still an issue with php related to this where a parent class cannot call a childs constant inside a parents method.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [`__get` and `__set`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get). <strike>I'm not really sure how it works with static constants though, you might only be able to work with instanced objects.</strike> [See G-Nugget's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791652/php-call-to-non-existing-class-constants-way-to-handle/12791685#comment17294579_12791685) regarding using them statically.

Comment: `__get()` and `__set()` are not called in a static contexts, but if you get creative, you can make the properties appear static.