# How/Can do I define a constant upon constant request?

Tags: php, class, static, constants

Alright, here it goes. This is what I am currently using, it works fine, but I got hung up on this idea...

```
class Estr {

    public static function __callStatic ( $name, $arguments ) {
        $class_vars = get_class_vars ( get_called_class ( ) );
        if ( is_array ( $class_vars ) && sizeof ( $class_vars ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( $class_vars as $key => $value ) {
                if ( strtolower ( $key ) == strtolower ( $name ) ) {
                    return $key;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



class Relationship extends Estr {

    public $alternate;

}
```

This allows me to call;

```
var_dump ( Relationship :: alternate ( ) ); // response "alternate"
```

All is well and great. However, when I started I wanted the following result;

```
var_dump ( Relationship :: alternate ); // response "alternate"
```

**And** I want my relationship class to be either;

```
class Relationship extends Estr {

    public $alternate;

}
```

*or*

```
class Relationship extends Estr {

    const alternate;

}
```

Where class Estr is handling returning the variable/constants name as the value, with a clean and OOP layout. (eg; 'const alternate = "alternate";' and 'const alternate = null;' are not desired.)

I attempted a few solutions, the closest I got to achieving the goal was attempting to catch the error of calling the undefined constant, while still returning the value. However, I still could not achieve the class hierarchy I desired.

Thanks for the noodle, enjoy the puzzle! XD

P.S.
Or better yet, how can I static call a non-existing class constant and handle the error within that class?
Eg; Relationship :: alternate
Response; "error within class Relationship"

Is there a way to intercept the call for a "defined constant," even though by nature they should exist? (If not, this may be answered here; [PHP => Call to non-existing class constants, way to handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791652/php-call-to-non-existing-class-constants-way-to-handle))